How to type check in .ts files using CJS?
I'm migrating a cjs node.js project from plain javascript to typescript. I'm following an incremental migration strategy where js files are gradually and slowly replaced with ts files. I understand requiring js files won't give me any type information. My problem, however, is that I'm also not getting any type information when a ts file requires another ts file using cjs syntax:
// myError.ts
module.exports = class MyError extends Error {
  // ...
}

// main.ts
const MyError = require("./myError");

When I hover my mouse over MyError in main.ts in VS code,

My expectation is that VS code will show the constructor type information.
My observation is that VS code shows any and does not run any type check on how the object is instantiated:

const GetStoreError: any

Now if I change the require syntax to ESM syntax in both files (export default in myError.ts, and import MyError from "xxx" in main.ts), type works correctly. My question, however, is that why CJS syntax in ts files doesn't work even though ts doc says it supports CJS in input files.
Why do I want to use cjs in ts files?
For consistency, because all existing code is written in CJS, and tsc compiles everything to CJS. And so i don't want ts files to use ESM syntax and create confusion about the actual runtime behavior.
Stack
Node version 20.13.1
typescript version 5.4.5
Some potentially relevant tsconfig settings:
"target": "ES2022",
"lib": ["ES2023"],
"module": "Node16",
"moduleResolution": "Node16",
"allowJs": true,
"checkJs": false,
"noEmit": false,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,

I'm not using any build tool aside from tsc.
My package.json does not define type, and so node infers everything as cjs.
tsc output files are in cjs (as expected) and look correct.
Any help is appreciated!
I tried tweaking tsconfig, setting type in package.json, and renaming files to cts - none worked.

If yout Typescript is set to compile to CJS, then you can still use import/export in Typescript and it will generate the correct module.export and require statements for you. This is arguably better and how everyone else writes Typescript, so I would strongly suggest this.

Also it's really strange that your actual typescript configuration is not set to commonjs.
